# SVNsharp how to get specified page?

Tags: c#, .net, svn, sharpsvn

How to get specified page of svn log using SvnClient class in SvnSharp;
For example i have secuence of commits with revisions [407, 402, 374, 373, 372, 371, 370, 369, 368, 367, 366, 365, 364]
I need to get secound page and page size 5, how to do that?

```
var logList = new Collection<SvnLogEventArgs>();
                var args = new SvnLogArgs();

                args.Limit = 10;
                svnClient.GetLog(new Uri(path), args, out logList);
```

Limit method is limit only first items without paging.

**Items should be extracted based on page and pagesize parameters. How to do that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subversion doesn't support paging. Calculating a page would take as long as retrieving all the data itself.

You might be able to optimize the request by passing the right revision numbers based upon your last request, but in that case you also have to make sure you properly handle cases where the path is copied from another location. (This is the reason why Subversion has to walk history anyway, and paging won't help improving performance)